# CKeditor uploading to S3, but not accessible in editor - RAILS - Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor, carrierwave, minimagick

rails 5.1.4
ruby 2.4.1
ckeditor 4.2.4
carrierwave 1.2.2
minimagick 4.8.0
fog-aws 2.0.1

I have ckeditor backed by carrierwave and it's connected to an S3 bucket. The image is being uploaded to the S3 bucket. I can see the files in there! BUT The ckeditor screen freezes and this is the output from heroku logs..rails server gives the same error. 
This is definitely a ckeditor config issue because I can upload a cover photo via the photos uploader where ckeditor is not the middle man. It's just an html file field using carrierwave and S3. I am able to recall the cover photo and display that from the S3 bucket so I know my credentials are good.

HEROKU LOGS:

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?&CKEditor=ckeditor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for IP ADDRESS

Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000038f2868 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180315-4-1xodi16.jpg>, @original_filename="coloursquare.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"coloursquare.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "ckCsrfToken"=>"56COpAWYrezg8OINmQYCmH6Hr1I5ZVxy1u9YtFmP", "CKEditor"=>"ckeditor", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}

DEBUG -- 

DEBUG -- SQL INSERT INTO "ckeditor_assets" ("data_file_name", "data_content_type", "data_file_size", "type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["data_file_name", "coloursquare.jpg"], ["data_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["data_file_size", 12893], ["type", "Ckeditor::Picture"], ["created_at", "2018-03-15 23:25:06.970758"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-15 23:25:06.970758"]]

heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/ckeditor/pictures?&CKEditor=ckeditor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" host=stormy-hollows-12083.herokuapp.com request_id=0e9fd60d-685e-4cd5-9296-413b68e0bf45 fwd="73.96.105.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=274ms status=500 bytes=1825 protocol=https

DEBUG -- COMMIT

INFO -- Completed 401 Unauthorized in 261ms (ActiveRecord: 27.2ms)

FATAL -- 

FATAL -- : ArgumentError (Version content doesn't exist!):

FATAL --  

FATAL -- : app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:4:in `url'

app/models/ckeditor/picture.rb:5:in `url_content'
```

CKEDITOR PICTURE UPLOADER.rb

```
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave  
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  def content_type_blacklist
    ['application/text', 'application/json']
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end

  def content_type_blacklist
    ['application/text', 'application/json']
  end
end
```

CKEDITOR config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.uiColor = '#ffffff';
  config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures?";
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.allowedContent = true;
}
```

MODEL 
CKEDITOR asset.rb

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase

  delegate :url, :current_path, :content_type, to: :data

  validates :data, presence: true
end
```

MODEL
CKEDITOR picture.rb

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  mount_uploader :data, CkeditorPictureUploader, mount_on: :data_file_name

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you're getting a 401 unauthorized, this means you have some type of permissions issue. Is this a private bucket?

Comment: they are not public but belong to me. I have permissions set up in the carrierwave initializer via .env. The photos are going into the bucket successfully. They are just not accessible to the editor after they've been uploaded.

Comment: hmm i'm not entirely sure what it is, but i believe its some type of authentication error your having if you're receiving a 401 after making a post request, double check all your keys

Comment: ya, just double checked, keys are good

Answer (score 0):

I found that in [Ckeditor::AssetResponse#asset_url](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb#L89) 
method, the `asset` object is not reloaded, so `asset.content_url` will always be nil thus caused the error. I fixed it like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly for `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile` class if you have it.